# How to best translate strings passed as variable to a Django module?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, ini, makemessages

I'm doing my first steps in Django and am trying to get translations of text to work which I'm passing into the application through an .ini file.

Say my `init.ini` is:

```
[test]
GREETING = Hello World
```

and in my `settings.py`, I'm doing:

```
from six.moves import configparser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Retrieve initialization configuration
init_parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
init_parser.read(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'init.ini'))

...
HELLO = init_parser.get('test', 'GREETING')
HELLO = _(init_parser.get('test', 'GREETING'))
```

my tags translations do not show up when calling `makemessage`.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/) says

> (The caveat with using variables or computed values, as in the
>   previous two examples, is that Django’s translation-string-detecting
>   utility, django-admin makemessages, won’t be able to find these
>   strings. More on makemessages later.)

but they although `makemessage` is covered aplenty on the documentation page, it does not provide a solution on how to translate variables/computed values like this. Thus my question:

Is there any recommended practical way of passing strings as variables into a python module and have `makemessage` catch them?

**EDIT**:
adding the extension as in `django-admin makemessages -l de --e=html,py,txt,ini` doesn't work either, but now I'm curious how I could make a `txt` file that would be covered. Maybe that's an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this `django-admin makemessages -l de --e=html,py,txt,ini` got me on the right track, because if `txt` is included by default as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files), it must work somehow.

I created `foo.txt`:

```
_("yeah why not")
{% trans "maybe like this" %}
```

and the second snippet showed up in the `.po` file when calling `makemessages`.

I created `foo.ini`:

```
_("from ini, yeah why not")
{% trans "from ini, maybe like this" %}
```

and running `django-admin makemessages -l de --e=html,py,txt,ini` included the second snippet in the `.po` file as well.

So *{% trans "" %}*-ifying all text snippets in the initialisation file seems to do the job. I can then fetch the translated value from in my module.

Comment: Sadly while translatable tags can be detected like this, they don't get translated automatically.

Comment: They do if you strip `{% trans "" %}` and translate by hand